# iOS AWS SDK - Why only Presigned-URL requests for background transfers?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, background, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I'd really like to get all the benefits of multipart transfers but this isn't possible with background transfers because they require the use of Pre-Signed URLs. The documentation says this is because you'd have to have separate pre-signed URLs for every part.

Do you know why background uploads/downloads can only be achieved using Pre-signed URLs with the iOS AWS SDK? I'm guessing it's a limitation of background NSURLSessions.

Do you know of a way (using the SDK) to get multipart goodness with background transfers?